Should we add BSP-tree as a synonym to binary space partitioning or just re-tag?
I noticed that the BSP-tree tag (3 questions) is not linked to the the binary space partitioning tag (29 questions & also synonyms with bsp). I don't have enough tag rep to propose synonyms using the default system, so I'm asking here: should we add BSP-tree as a synonym to binary space partitioning? Or, since the load is small, should we just re-tag the 3 BSP-tree questions we have?
Related reading: Can/should we rename [bsp] to [binary-space-partitioning] (with an alias)?

I don't think we need a synonym here since we only have three questions. One question needs to have the tag changed while the two others already have the binary-space-partitioning, so these two just need to be edited to have the "bad" tag removed.

Sounds good, I have made the edits as indicated.
